# Is it possible to have a static and dynamic home page at the same time?? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

As the title says. I would like to know if it is possible to have a static and dynamic page at the same time in my main page, or it must necessarily be static or dynamic. I read several forums but I do not find clear answers. I know that if I want it to be static I must create a template or in the case of being dynamic use the file front-page.php. I can not make my static template dynamic? Or embedding static code on the front-page.php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can have a home page that has both static as well as dynamic content in it. You will need to create a new template. In the template put your static content. Then use php codex for the part that you want to be dynamic. The dynamic part can be pulled from a post or a page, that is your choice. I hope this helps.

Comment: So I can put dynamic code if in Wordpress to establish that my home page is static ?? There are no limitations ?. Thank you very much

Comment: your comment doesnt make sense, but yes, you can have both static and dynamic content on any page of a custom template, without any limitations.

Comment: My english is very bad, sorry. Excellent. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It can possible. You can create a custom template for your theme. It is static when you need to set dynamic you need to assign the same template to the page. There is no limitation on it.

Note: *you need to add those dynamic filed into custom template.*